# Crash llibobjc.A.dylib objc_release + 36

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, crashlytics

I use crashlytics to get the crashes of my app, i am currently Crashlytics version: 3.9.3. Some users are getting a crash that I cannot seem to repro on my machine. This is the logs from Fabric:

```
    Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos
        EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x00004a4b9a43bec8

    #37. Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos
    0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x7fff6b43d184 objc_release + 36
    1  MyApp                        0x10805ad2d __66-[AppManager getCountriesDelegate:]_block_invoke (AppManager.m:1412)
    2  libdispatch.dylib              0x7fff6c006591 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    3  libdispatch.dylib              0x7fff6bffed50 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    4  libdispatch.dylib              0x7fff6c00bc61 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 880
    5  libdispatch.dylib              0x7fff6c000941 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 515
    6  libdispatch.dylib              0x7fff6c0006ed _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 101
    7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x7fff6c2c31ca _pthread_wqthread + 1387
    8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x7fff6c2c2c4d start_wqthread + 13

- (void) getCountriesDelegate:(id<AppManagerDelegate>)delegate
{
    __weak __typeof(id<AppManagerDelegate>) weakDelegate  = delegate;
    __weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{ //my function definition 

 });
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: It means that something is releasing a pointer which is not a valid object pointer. Is this with ARC or are you manually calling `-release` on something?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiples reasons why you can get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS error code. [Appel's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2004/tn2123.html#SECCRASHLOGEXCEPTION) says:

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS/KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS — This is caused by the thread
>   accessing unmapped memory. It may be triggered by either a data access
>   or an instruction fetch; the Thread State section describes how to
>   tell the difference.

You should look deeply at your class `AppManager`. As the crashlog said's the crash occurs at line 1412 of file `AppManager.m` in the method `getCountriesWithRespectToPurposeAndFavoriteDelegate:`.

Comment: Yes i have already deeply look at line 1412 also go through our hole function :( but couldn't find